# SQL Subtract Values From Table 1 When The Row Exists In Table 2

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have two tables, tblTasks and tblOffsets. The tblTasks has all of these Tasks that are being funded and tblOffsets has references to lines in tblTasks that are being funded by outside money.

Both have the same columns except tblOffsets has an extra column called "Source" to keep track of where the money is coming form.

> ### Columns
>
> Appropriation, PerformerGroup, Performer, Contract, ID, IDExt, Labor, Material, Travel, FiscalYear

---

The primary key is actually a collection of columns from this table: Appropriation, PerformerGroup, Performer, Contract, FiscalYear, ID, and IDExt. Each row has a unique combination of these columns.

Now what I want to do is get a subquery (or maybe I need to make a new table?) that takes tblTasks and subtracts the values from tblOffsets for the lines that exist in tblOffsets.

I've tried to write this code that obviously doesn't work but it should give you an idea of what I'm talking about:

```
SELECT 
tb.Appropriation,
tb.PerformerGroupID,
tb.PerformerID,
tb.Contract,
tb.ID,
tb.IDExt,
(tb.Labor - o.Labor) AS Labor,
(tb.Material - o.Material) AS Material,
(tb.Travel - o.Travel) AS Travel

FROM tblTaskBooks tb, tblOffsets o

WHERE tblTaskBooks.Appropriation = tblOffsets.Appropriation
AND   tblTaskBooks.PerformerGroupID=  tblOffsets.PerformerGroupID 
AND   tblTaskBooks.PerformerID = tblOffsets.PerformerID 
AND   tblTaskBooks.Contract = tblOffsets.Contract
AND   tblTaskBooks.ID = tblOffsets.ID
AND   tblTaskBooks.IDExt = tblOffsets.IDExt
AND   tblTaskBooks.FiscalYear = tblOffsets.FiscalYear
```

When I do this however, Access keeps asking for an input for Appropriation and etc. Is the problem that the two tables have different number of rows?

Comment: You are probably quite close. When there are different numbers of rows, outer joins are often useful. Outer joins bring in row values of a second table only when they exist, but still always bring in the first table.

Comment: Turns out Access just really likes for you to specify Left Join. I got it!